# MySQL Group By with multi-join

Tags: mysql

here is my SQL query:

```
    `SELECT subject, threadpost.date, threadpost.idThreadPost as id,
    threadcategories.category, users.userName, COUNT(idThreadSubs) AS subs, COUNT(idThreadReplies) as replies
    FROM threadpost
      JOIN threadcategories
        ON idthreadcategories = threadpost.category
      JOIN users
        ON idUsers = UserId
      LEFT JOIN threadsubs
        ON threadpost.idThreadPost = threadsubs.ThreadId
      LEFT JOIN threadreplies
        ON threadpost.idThreadPost = threadreplies.ThreadId
    WHERE idthreadcategories LIKE ?
    GROUP BY idThreadPost
    ORDER BY date desc
    LIMIT 20;`
```

the problem comes with adding COUNT(idThreadReplies). As you can see, I'm grouping by idThreadPost. This is because I want to retrieve both the count of subscriptions to the thread, and the count of replies.

However, the result gives me the incorrect number of replies (the same number as subscriptions).

How would I formulate this query correctly?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. solution is to use subqueries in the joins that require group by:

```
    `SELECT subject, threadpost.date, threadpost.idThreadPost as id,
    threadcategories.category, users.userName, tsubs.subs AS subs, trep.replies as replies
    FROM threadpost
      JOIN threadcategories
        ON idthreadcategories = threadpost.category
      JOIN users
        ON idUsers = UserId
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT threadsubs.ThreadId as tsubId, COUNT(idThreadSubs) as subs
        FROM threadsubs
        GROUP BY idThreadSubs
      ) as tsubs
        ON tsubs.tsubId = threadpost.idThreadPost
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT threadreplies.ThreadId as tId, COUNT(threadreplies.idThreadReplies) as replies
        FROM threadreplies
        GROUP BY threadreplies.ThreadId
      ) AS trep
        ON trep.tId = threadpost.idThreadPost
    WHERE idthreadcategories LIKE ?
    ORDER BY date desc
    LIMIT 20;`
```